# what is the prototype object of Location object?

Tags: javascript, prototype

location is the owned property of window and document.

```
window.hasOwnProperty("location")
true

document.hasOwnProperty("location")
true
```

But when i tried to compare prototype of location with Location.prototype, i got error that Location is not defined.

Although i can see Location constructor in the Location object.

What is the prototype object of location?

Ideally we should be able to see Location.prototype and methods on it like assign and other two.

Chrome bug?
[image]

Comment: Prototype is used for adding new function to your object. It is littlebit advanced.

Comment: Some clarification on [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-location): `window.location` must be an object of type `Location`, but it says nothing about whether `Location` needs to be visible to scripts -- `Location`, in the spec, is just an interface of properties and functions. Firefox, for example, chokes on `Object.getPrototypeOf(window.location)` and doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A prototype may not be visible, even if it's listed.

Try this :

```
​var a = (function(){ // this is a closure protecting A
    var A = function(b){
        this.b = b;
    }
    return new A('test');
})();
console.log(a); // logs ▸A
console.log(A); // error, as A isn't defined
```

There is no reason for the browser to make `Location` visible. And certainly no reason for it to clutter the global namespace.

Comment: seems you are correct but it should be read only instead of hidden. In fact Window.prototype is read only but visible.

Comment: Which specification says that it "*should*" it be that way?

Comment: @apsillers exactly that information, i am looking. W3C doesn't talk about the attributes of DOM objects

Comment: @Praveen A starting point: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-location

Answer (score 1):

w3 calls the location object an "interface", see http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#location
so it is propably no goot idea to extend the prototype of it.

Why do you want to extend the prototype of Location?
Is there a better way to solve your origin problem?